# ¿Cómo puedo crear un arreglo de Strings en base a un archivo de texto?

Tags: java

Verán, lo que yo hice fue crear 2 clases, una clase principal, y una clase que contenga operaciones que realizare con las cadenas de texto. Como primer paso para resolver mi problema fue crear un método que leyera una dirección de archivo mandada desde la clase main y este texto se guardara en una variable.

```
public String leerArchivoTxT(String direccionArchivo){
    String texto = ""; 
    try{ 
        BufferedReader bf  = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(direccionArchivo));
        String temporal = ""; 
        String bfRead;
        while((bfRead = bf.readLine()) != null){ 
            temporal = temporal + bfRead; 
        }
        texto = temporal; 
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("No se encontro archivo ");
    }
    
    return texto; // regresamos el texto guardado
}
```

luego lo pase a una variable dentro de la clase main

```
String texto;
texto = cadena.leerArchivoTxT(direccionDelArchivo);
```

Pero esto solo mi sirvió para guardar como tal todo el texto del archivo cuando mi intención es guardar en un arreglo unidimensional distintos Strings leídos de un solo archivo, teniendo en cuenta que cada linea del texto leído contara como un espacio en el arreglo.
Ejemplo:

```
Esta noche salí
con mis amigos
al cine.
```

Posición del String: 0. Esta noche salí | 1. con mis amigos | 2. al cine.

¿Hay alguna forma de separar el String en base a quizá las tabulaciones detectadas o algo por el estilo?
¿Requiero otra solución?

Comment: Lo que necesitas es almacenar cada línea del archivo de texto en un array?? o partir la cadena completa en varios fragmentos. De cualquier forma héchale un vistazo a [éste tutorial](https://jarroba.com/arraylist-en-java-ejemplos/) para ver si  [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) cumple con lo que necesitas, solo tendrías que usarlo dentro del `while` en el caso de que necesites almacenar cada línea del archivo. Saludos ;)

Comment: @Israel-ICM realmente cualquiera de las 2 formas que mencionaste me serviría, solo mencione lo de partir la cadena porque no quería confundirme mas con el código y modificarlo mucho. Veré enseguida las cosas que me pasaste, gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo reemplaza la concatenación de la variable **temporal** y adiciona cada línea leída a un [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) y retórnalo en lugar de retornar la cadena de la siguiente forma:

```
public ArrayList<String> leerArchivoTxT(String direccionArchivo){
    ArrayList<String> arrLineas = new ArrayList<String>(); // Instanciamos el array
    try{ 
        BufferedReader bf  = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(direccionArchivo));
        String bfRead;
        while ((bfRead = bf.readLine()) != null) {
            arrLineas.add(bfRead); // Adicionamos cada linea al array
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("No se encontro archivo ");
    }
    
    return arrLineas; // regresamos el array guardado
}
```

Espero te sirva saludos. ;)